# button shoud be relative to right side collapse bar in css

Tags: html, css

I have a button, which should be relative form right side collapse bar.
when the collapse bar is expanded it is going down of the collapse bar,
but what I need is it should be relative to the collapse bar on right side, if it is expanded or collapse, it should show relative to the right side bar

```css
 .rightButton {
        flex-grow: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 3em;
        z-index: 0;
        float: right;
        width: 2em;
        padding: 3px 3px 4px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
```

Where collapse bar and rightbutton are two different classes.

Comment: Can you add your html?

Comment: How do you collapse that div? What's the global layout?

Comment: we cannot help you without knowing your html code.